# Debugging ASP.NET Web API 2 on linux with Rider

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, .net-4.5, rider

### `Assertion at debugger-agent.c:1648, condition *endbuf <= limit' not met1`

I have a project on ASP.NET Web API 2, and working on it with Rider (2018.3.4). I tried to debug it, but the mono xsp4(which is the server used to host the API locally) server is crashing ...
Here is the log
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fy0p.jpg

Full Error Stack Trace  https://pastebin.com/b8rerDL8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, by asking  the JetBrains team, Here is the step that I followed
1.disabling **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger -> [ ]Allow property evaluations and other implicit function calls** 
[image]

2.disabling **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger -> [ ] Break unhandled exception**
[image]

=> Note that I also shift to Rider 2019 cause the problem still exist on 2018